# linear space proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question is that V is the span of these vectors in the diagram b2,b3,b4.
Please help me in this problem, I know all the theory that for it to be a linear space it should be closed under addition and multiplication and contain the zero vector. Can someone prove it for this particular vectors that this is a valid linear space. Please tell me the proof for this particular vector space.[image]

Comment: The proof that the span of these particular vectors is a vector space is that it's a special case of the theorem that says that the span of any set of vectors is a vector space. Do you know how that proof goes?

Comment: It seems like the question might be asking for something other than just showing this is a vector space - as Gerry points out, the span of any set of vectors is a vector space. What is the exact text of the question?

Comment: Consider now the set V3 of all vectors of the form qb2 + rb3 + sb4, where q, r, s are real numbers. Show that V3 is a linear space, and show also that it has dimension 3.

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is a set of vectors then by **definition** the span of $S$ is the smallest vector space containing $S$ and it's also the set of all linear combinations of elements of $S$.

Knowing this then for your question $V$ is a vector space by definition and you have not to prove anything.

Comment: Consider now the set V3 of all vectors of the form qb2 + rb3 + sb4, where q, r, s are real numbers. Show that V3 is a linear space, and show also that it has dimension 3.

Comment: As I said $V_3$ is the set of all linear combinations of $b_2,b_3$ and $b_4$ so it's the span of these vectors. Of course we can prove that $V_3$ is a linear space by hand. For the dimension check that these vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: The marking scheme of my exam paper tells that proof that it is closed under addition is sufficient to prove that it's a linear space, this is the problem how do I show this ? That it is closed under addition using these three vectors?

Comment: Yes this set is closed under addition and multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: You prove that it is closed under addition by proving that the span of any set of vectors is closed under addition. Have you ever successfully proved that something is a vector space? How did you prove it was closed under addition?

Comment: @user63181, I would say that the span is defined to be the set of all linear combinations, which is then proved to be the smallest vector space containing $S$.

Comment: yes that's what I'm asking why is it closed under addition ? Can u prove it pleasee

Comment: Suppose $x$ and $y$ are both in the span of $\{\,v_1,v_2,\dots,v_3\,\}$. Then $x=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\cdots+a_nv_n$ and $y=b_1v_1+b_2v_2+\cdots+b_nv_n$ for some scalars $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n,b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$. Then $x+y=c_1c_v+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_nv_n$ where $c_1=a_1+b_1,c_2=a_2+b_2,\dots,c_n=a_n+b_n$, so $x+y$ is also in the span.